# JSTL: как соединить значение переменных?

Tags: jsp, jstl

У меня такой код в JSP:

```
У меня 
  <c:forEach items="${storageListStorage+shopId}" var="storage">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${storage.productDto.categoryDto.nameCategory}"> </c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${storage.productDto.brand}"> </c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${storage.productDto.nameProduct}"> </c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${storage.amount}"> </c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${storage.shopDto.id}"> </c:out></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

**Как получить значение двух переменных из сессии в items?** В storageListStorage у меня y находится список и в зависимости от shopId, должен выдаваться соответствующих список. При таком синтаксисе: `items="${storageListStorage+shopId}"`, мне выдает ошибку. Если я пишу просто `items="${storageListStorage1}`, то все работает. Кто может подсказать решение?

Comment: Почему бы Вам не сделать `Map<Integer, Storage>`, не назвать его например `storageMap` и не применить `Items="${storageMap[shopId]}"`? А так не догадались ещё в EL вычислять имена переменных. Непростое это дело.

Comment: Можно ещё функцию попробовать `public Storage storageFunc(Integer shopId) { if (shopId == 1) return storageListStorage1; ... }`, `items="${storageFunc(shopId)}"`.

Comment: @Sergey не рекомендуется в JSP использовать JAVA код, но попробую и такой вариант, спасибо)
п.с. что такое EL? )

Comment: Вообще-то я не думал про java в JSP. Как Ваши storageListStorage и shopId в JSP попадают? Точно так же и map и function, т.е. свойства и методы того, что называют моделью.